# Not found my staticfiles in django 1.9

Tags: python, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have a little problem with Django , it is not my static files.
I have read the documentation , I tried putting the path directly , use {{ STATIC_URL }} and most recommended method is to leave the details. Any idea how to fix it ?
template.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/normalize.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/demo.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/component.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/cs-select.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/cs-skin-boxes.css' %}" />
```

local.py (settings)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

`STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR2.child('static')]`

my file folder in the right direction
[The first folder is the virtualenv, the second folder is for Django Project where is the manage.py (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70zwJ.png)

Views, models, urls and forms working properly, and display the chosen template
[The python code working properly (image)][2]

#### Update

I try change STATICFILES_DIRS for this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static', ),
)
```

And for and printed the path to make sure it is correct, but the the error continues.
[The result of print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZLPi.png)
Thanks in advance

Comment: I've resolved for Django 1.9 is:                                                                  `STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR, 'static')`

Answer (score 7):

I've resolved for Django 1.9 is: `STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR, 'static')`

Comment: also valid for django 1.10 ;)

Answer (score 1):

To start, I would make `STATICFILES_DIRS` a tuple.

Next, I would try a format like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static', 'static_dirs'),
)
```

To make sure it is going to the right directory, `print` the path and adjust accordingly:

```
print os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static', 'static_dirs')
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for taking the time to give me an idea. Unfortunately , not working. Imprimi route , and correct, but not working . ( I leave a screenshot of the console. ) Any other ideas ?

Comment: @RRenéAlcántara How do you have your `STATIC_ROOT` configured? Trying doing something similar to this: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),  'static', 'static')`. Additionally, take a look at this answer I provided. Maybe try to mimic the setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957604/django-1-8-static-files-doesnt-work/29957796#29957796

Comment: Sorry, it has not worked. It has set the root, so I put what he said in the link you passed me. `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')` However, it did not work and I marked the error saying it can not be used STATICFILES_DIRS if the root is used. I'm still investigating, but find nothing. Any other ideas? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve that problem on mac by using:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static').replace('\\','/'),]
```